# writing bytes to file in python

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing bittorrent client. It can download pieces from peers, but I can't make it write pieces to files correctly. The problem is the encoding. Because of the wrong encoding client is writing wrong bytes to file. I have found encoding called "unicode_internal". It seems to be correct one but the problem didn't go away. Despite the constant piece size(16384 bytes) sometimes the file size increases by 16386 or so.
Here's how I write pieces to file. Nothing special.

```
with open(path, 'a', encoding='unicode_internal') as f:
    f.seek(offset, 0)
    f.write(data.decode('unicode_internal'))
```

I tryed to open file in 'rb' mode but it doesn't help.
Part of the stdout from working client:

```
piece size: 16384
sum of pieces lengths: 49152
filesize: 49152

piece size: 16384
sum of pieces lengths: 65536
filesize: 65536

piece size: 16384
sum of pieces lengths: 81920
filesize: 81922 #Here it is. Size increased by 16386 bytes. The piece size is 16384

piece size: 16384
sum of pieces lengths: 98304
filesize: 98306
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `data`? `str` or `bytes`?

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7. data is bytes, then it converts to str

Comment: Why are you even trying to use an encoding? You have bytes, write to a `wb` or `ab` binary file. No decoding, no encoding. You'll have problems with newline translation otherwise.

Comment: are you writing bytes or str?

Comment: I suggest using `data.decode('latin1')` because all arbitrary binary strings are valid `latin1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open file in binary mode at write `bytes`:

```
data = bytes(...) # some data in bytes type
with open(path, 'ab') as f:
    f.seek(offset, 0)
    f.write(data)
```

When opening in text mode, independently of used encoding, Python can do transformations with line-ending. E.g. on Windows it will convert single line-feed character `\n` (`0x0A`) to "Windows-style line-ending": `\r\n` (`0x0D`, `0x0A`) — two characters.